# Publishing from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment, publish

I am trying to publish my ASP.NET 5 MVC6 application to godaddy server from Visual Studio 2015. I have imported publish profile from my server and I am able to validate the connection.  However, when I publish my app I have the following error:

> ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED
>
> Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer
>   ("XXXXXXX") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize.
>   Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that
>   the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials
>   represent a user who has permissions to access the site.

The credentials are valid, I can publish VS2013 sample project from VS2015, but I can not publish VS2015 sample project as well as my app from VS2015 with the same credentials.

The user is an admin on the server.

Comment: Can you publish that same sample-app from VS2015? You can open the solution without any changes, trying it would take only minutes.
If the works, the settings from your app are probably incorrect.

Comment: Luc, I can publish VS2013 sample project from VS2015, but I can not publish VS2015 sample project as well as my app from VS2015 with the same credentials.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing you need to check is if GoDaddy supports 4.5.1 on their server. Once this is confirmed? We can start working!

Helios (the shim between IIS and ASP.NET 5) requires at least 4.5.1 to run so this is why it's essential.

Only thing missing is running a `dnu publish` and making sure that you have a web.config with this section in it:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

If it doesn't work, I would get in touch with GoDaddy for some support. If they do not support the latest version of the framework, you might have to revert to MVC 5 or switch to [azure-web-sites](/questions/tagged/azure-web-sites) if you really want to enable [asp.net-mvc-6](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-6).

Comment: ASP.net version is 4.5.2. I added runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" in web.config, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Have you checked with GoDaddy if they support it?

Comment: Yes, they do support it.